# If $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f(x)f'(x)\le 0$ for all $x\ge 0$, must there be $f(x)\equiv0$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

Let $f(x)$ be a continuously derivable function on interval $[0,+\infty)$. If $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f(x)f'(x)\le 0$ for all $x\ge 0$, I wonder whether there must be $f(x)\equiv0$.

Update: $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)^2)=2f(x)f'(x)\le 0$, which implies $f(x)\equiv0$. Can this proof work?

Comment: I am even failing to plot a graph of f(x) as f(x) is starting from origin, if f(x) will be positive how can f'(x) be negative?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Your condition says that $$\frac{d}{dx}(f^2) \le 0$$ and so $f^2$ is decreasing. However, $f^2 \ge 0$ and $f(0)^2 = 0$ so we must have $f^2 \equiv 0$, which is the same as $f \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $\varphi(x) = f(x)^2$, so that $\varphi \geq 0$ and $\varphi(0) = 0$.
Since $\varphi'(x) = 2 f(x)f'(x)\leq 0$, you have that $\varphi$ is non increasing, but then it must be $0$ for every $x\geq 0$:
$$
0 = \varphi(0) \geq \varphi(x) \geq 0.
$$